# Pass generic resolve object to ui-bootstrap modal via modalService

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've been following this [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-angularjs-modal-service) post about building a generic modal service. This part has gone well so far (I won't copy the service code in here). I'm trying to build a modal that contains several options for editing data.

To do so, I'm using the service, and pass in several functions on a resolve param, somewhat like this (I'm adapting the code from the blog, to fit what I'm trying to do) :

```
app.module('yourModuleName').controller('CustomerEditController', ['$scope', '$location', 
        '$routeParams', '$timeout', 'config', 'dataService', 'modalService',
        function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, $timeout, config, 
                  dataService, modalService) {
    $scope.updateName = function(customerId,name){
        dataService.updateName(customerId,name);
    }
    $scope.editCustomer = function (customer) {
        dataService.lockCustomer(customer.id);
        var custName = customer.firstName + ' ' + customer.lastName;

        var modalOptions = {
            closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
            actionButtonText: 'Confirm Edit',
            headerText: 'Edit ' + custName + '?',
            bodyText: 'Select edit option.'
        };
        var modalDefaults = {
            resolve : {
                updateName: function(){
                    return $scope.updateName
                },
                customer: function(){
                    return customer
                },
            }
        }

        modalService.showModal(modalDefaults, modalOptions).finally(function (result) {
        dataService.unlockCustomer(customer.id);
        });
    }
}]);
```

But when I open the modal, none of the `$scope` objects have resolved, nor has `customer` which I pass in. If I log the object, wrapped in `JSON.stringify` I get an empty object. If I log the bare object, firefox holds a reference, and shows me the properly filled in object.

I was expecting the issue to be with scope phase so I wrapped the `modalService` call in a `$timeout`, with no effect. I then thought it might be that I've not injected the items in the resolve into the controller, so I looked into the demo projects and copied some of the code (again with my adaptations). hoping it would help:

```
if (!tempModalDefaults.controller) {
    tempModalDefaults.controller = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.modalOptions = tempModalOptions;
        $scope.modalOptions.ok = function (result) {
            $modalInstance.close('ok');
        };
        $scope.modalOptions.close = function (result) {
            $modalInstance.close('cancel');
        };
    };

    var injectParams = ['$scope', '$modalInstance'];
    if(tempModalDefaults.resolve){
        injectPramas.concat(_.keys(tempModalDefaults.resolve))
    }
    tempModalDefaults.controller.$inject = injectParams
}
```

Specifically the later part that injects params. Still no effect.

I feel like this should be a fairly simple matter, as it's not a massively unusual situation.

What have I missed, that will let me use the functions I want to pass through the resolve param?

Comment: First of all, it seems that your entire question is based on code in a blog post. The question should stand on its own without relying on external links. But, even if I grant you that the "resolve" behaves as one might expect (like it does in `ui.bootstrap`'s `$modal`), then each resolve parameter expects a value or a promise, and at least with `updateName` function, that is not what happens

Comment: @newdev I've tried to strike a balance between putting to much code in this question vs relying on external links. Regardless, I've certainly used the resolved parameter to deliver non-promise data. If you want to post an answer elaborating on your point that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @newdev I just found the description of resolve in [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) in ng-route. The language it uses implies the values may or may not be promises  *If string then it is an alias for a service. Otherwise if function, then it is injected and the return value is treated as the dependency. **If** the result is a promise, it is resolved before its value is injected into the controller.*

Comment: Right... and my point was that `updateName` is a function that doesn't return anything; neither a value nor a function. As for external links - think of it like this: if the link is broken, would you question make any sense to a future visitor?

Comment: @newdev unless I'm mistaken the updateName function that's part of the resolve param,  returns the function in the scope. This is so it can be exposed on the modal's scope,  and bound to an ng-click attribute. I'll concede on your other point.  I'll update the question at home tonight.

Comment: Yes, exactly.. it would return a function variable. If that is what you wanted, then that's fine. But you were talking about parameters not yet being resolved, so I assumed you expected the function to return a promise of a value. Anyway... :)

Comment: The resolve object (e.g. tempDefaults.resolve) appears as empty in my logs, when toString'd but is 'filled in' when I log the object.